# Does a SAPUI5 aggregation binding have a timing or rendering delay?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a sap.m.List, with an aggregation of items bound to a model.

If I load new data for a single item in my list, and replace an item in my model with the new item, my aggregation automatically updates (note: I have already received data from the backend, it's just JavaScript from here).

This is a simplified depiction of my list:

```
   var oList = new sap.m.List( {
      items: {
        path: "oModel>/resource/list",
        factory: function(sId, oContext) {
          var oItem = new sap.ui.jsfragment("fragments.myItem", oController);
          oItem.iId = oContext.getProperty("id");
          return oItem;
        }
      }
    });

 function updateSingleListItemInModel(oNewItem) {
        //custom function which overrides a single list entry
        }

  function focusActiveItem() {
    var oItem = oList.getSelectedItem();
    if (oItem) {
      oItem.focus();
       }
    }
```

The following does **not** focus the selected item:

```
updateSingleListItemInModel()
focusActiveItem(oNewItem);
```

The following **does** focus the selected item:

```
updateSingleListItemInModel()
setTimeout(function() {
   focusActiveItem(oNewItem);
            }, 5);
```

Note that the only difference is 5 ms delay, during which no backend loading occurs. Does the SAPUI5 aggregation binding have a delay (in this case somewhere between 0 and 5 ms)? Or is the rendering too slow, and does can it not focus because the item hasn't rendered yet? Or is something else happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and tell me if it works:

```
oList.addEventDelegate({
  onAfterRendering: function(){
    var oItem = oList.getSelectedItem();
    if (oItem){
      oItem.focus();
    }
  }
}, this);
```